# Combobox with itemcontainerstyle selected item background

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a comobox defined as follows:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentLineItem.Location, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Location" DisplayMemberPath="Location" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CurrentLineItem.Editing, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentLineItem.LocationDetails}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Location, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OnHand, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:N4\}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Allocated, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:N4\}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="3" Text="0.0000"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

This is working fine except that I want the selected item to be highlighted with a blue background. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentLineItem.Location, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Location" DisplayMemberPath="Location" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CurrentLineItem.Editing, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentLineItem.LocationDetails}">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Location, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OnHand, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:N4\}}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Allocated, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:N4\}}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="3" Text="0.0000"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: This does not work. The "IsSelected" path is underlined in Blue. When I hover over it I see: "Cannot resolve property 'IsSelected' in data context of type 'Business.LineItemInfo'; which is the bound data context for the container.

Comment: I have updated the answer (changed to TemplatedParent) I've tested on my computer using a fake datasource and it works, Using TemplatedParent you reference to the element with the template, in this case your ComboboxItem.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. Same message for the "IsSelected" property.